How to create my own ex command in AstroNvim, nvim, macOS
I want to add ex command to AstroNvim so that when i type
:rn

it does:
:!python3 path_to_current_file

so that i could save some typing, if rn command already does something then rename it to :rnf or :rncf
I asked chatGPT and bingAI, but they gave me different responses every time I asked. I also searched it up but did not found answer, my ~/.config directory looks like that if it helps:
 .config
├──  init.lua
├──  lazy-lock.json
├──  lua
│  ├──  community.lua
│  ├──  lazy_setup.lua
│  ├──  plugins
│  │  ├──  astrocore.lua
│  │  ├──  astrolsp.lua
│  │  ├──  astroui.lua
│  │  ├──  mason.lua
│  │  ├──  myplugs.lua
│  │  ├──  none-ls.lua
│  │  ├──  treesitter.lua
│  │  └──  user.lua
│  └──  polish.lua
├──  neovim.yml
├──  README.md
└──  selene.toml 


I just figured out about nvim_create_user_command, in init.lua add this:


vim.api.nvim_create_user_command("Run", function() vim.cmd("!python3 " .. vim.fn.expand "%") end, {})



or in lua/plugins add lua file with this:


vim.api.nvim_create_user_command("Run", function() vim.cmd("!python3 " .. vim.fn.expand "%") end, {})

return {}



Also name of the command must be capitalized, so :rn is not valid.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
